# Is the origin of a coordinate system also called "origo"?

Tags: mathematics, danish

In a coordinate system, the (0,0)-point where the axes meet is mathematically called *the origin* in text-books and in texts I can find online - e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_(mathematics)).

In my mothertongue Danish, we instead use the mathematical word *origo* (which sounds like nothing Danish - rather latin, I would guess).

Now, I have a digital Danish-English [dictionary](http://www.ordbogen.com/opslag.php?word=origo&dict=a000) at hand (well-recognized, as far as I know), and when looking it up, the result was:

[image]

In Danish, of course, but let me translate the four results:

> - **origo** -The linguists discussed the origo of the word
> - **origin** -He wrote an article about the origin of language
> - **beginning** -She has been researching the beginning of language for many years
> - **originate** -The dictionary explained from where the word originated

This dictionary suggests to me that the word *origo* does exist in English. But none of the four results concern the mathematical meaning as the origin of the coordinate system.

So, is it correct that this word exists? And if so, is the meaning the same as *coordinate system origin*?

Comment: I have never come across it, and I studied maths to degree level. It appears to be a technical term used in [pragmatics](https://findwords.info/term/origo) (whatever that is).

Comment: @Mick Ok, I see. It seems to exist but not in the same meaning as we use it over here.

Comment: I would classify it as a loan word. The term [*ab origo*](https://glosbe.com/la/en/ab%20origo) (from the beginning) seems to exist, but I couldn't tell you where it is used. Interesting question. +1

Comment: The correct places to check are English dictionaries, and relevant maths articles etc in English. A word found only in the latter would be arguably off-topic on ELU.

Comment: The full (subscription-only) OED does actually list [***fons et origo***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/72620?rskey=z0IopU&result=1#eid3957266) (Latin: *source and origin*), but that hardly makes ***origo*** a "word" in English. In their definitions for ***origin***, OED does include 2c: *Math. A fixed point from which measurement or motion commences; **spec.  (a) the point of intersection of the axes in Cartesian coordinates;**  (b) the pole in polar coordinates.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about an *English* term.

Comment: *Origo* is the Latin word from which E *origin* derives (the stem on which the other cases of *origo* are built is *origin-*). It is sometimes used in linguistics to designate the speaking point from which deictic references are pointed to, much as L *ego* = "I" is used in kinship studies to designate the speaking individual who employs various terms for his relations.

Comment: I have never seen/heard "origo", to my recollection.  However, during the period of roughly 1965-1980 there was a lot of "cross-pollination" between Dutch and English/US mathematicians and computer scientists, so the word may have been "borrowed" from Dutch by a few English-language authors.

Comment: Define “we”. I have never heard the word _origo_ either, and linguists definitely do not discuss the origo of a word in Danish (_oprindelse_ is the word used there). Note that ordbogen.com is not as well-recognised a dictionary as most others. It's useful, but the rate of error is much higher than, say, Gyldendal. This looks like something that was suggested by a user and then over-confidently added to the dictionary.

Comment: I've only ever heard the word "origo" in a training course for a structural analysis program. The course was ostensibly in English, but it was Danish software, being taught by its Danish programmer, to a predominantly Danish audience. In English, I would always use the English word, which is "origin".

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback. I'm a bit surprised, though, by the doubt in the *Danish* existence of the word among these comments. Let me clearify that it certainly *does* exist in Danish in the mathematical world - it is being taught to university students, see e.g. [this online syllabus chapter](http://01005.mat.dtu.dk/materialer/enoter/afsnit/NUID12-tn6/) from the fundamental "Advanced Mathematics" university course at DTU, where the word "origo" is being introduced and defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heard origo used in math or physics. Nor is **origo** in the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=origo&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch).  When I enter origo, I get:

> No dictionary entries found for ‘origo’.
>
> Did you mean:
>
> •oligo
>
> •amigo
>
> •aurigo
>
> •brig
>
> •brio
>
> Check your search and try again

There is no entry for origo in Etomonline, neither [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=o&p=12&allowed_in_frame=0) nor on the following page.

(My advice, amigo, is if you want to use origo in mathematics, do it with [brio](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brio) or not at all. :))

Answer (score 3):

Even as a Mathematics student, I've never come across it, so it's better to use a well-known term in the first place, otherwise you might just end up with confusing readers.

Comment: Unsubstantiated responses and obvious advice such as given here are not suitable 'answers' on ELU, and should be given as 'comments'. Note Mick's contribution.  // I taught maths beyond A-Level for years, but would not assume I'd encountered all terminology.

Answer (score -2):

**Modifying philosopher out of post because of confusion.**

The English word is *origin*.

In English math you can use origin to represent 0,0 as that is where you are measuring from.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_(mathematics)

The Danish word *origo*, used in English means the same thing but in the context of speaking. If I said "My car is in front of me", I am the origo.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/origo

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origo

Comment: When Descartes wrote, "Cogito ergo sum", he was not thinking of the Cartesian coordinate system. Please read *Discours de la mèthode* before making patently false statements like this.

Comment: The word in question is *origo*, not *erigo*; *Ergo* means therefore in Latin, and it means therefore in English. Descartes' CES has nothing to do with orthogonal coordinate systems. It was intended to provide a foundation from which to refute the infinite regress of doubt about existence. Descartes probably meant to say *Cogito cogitare ergo cogito esse* In any case, I think your answer is a magnificent troll, which I have therefore declined to downvote. Well played!

Comment: I'm not here for votes, I know 90% of people are idiots on the internet :)

Comment: In its edited state, this is worthy of an upvote; +1 from me. As a side note, the hypothesis in the earlier version that _ergo_ is related to _origo_ does not hold up: _ergo_ is from Old Latin _*ē regō_ (or _*ē rogō_) ‘straightforward, along the straight way’, while _orīgō/orīgin-_ is derived from the verb _orior_ ‘rise, come to be’.

Comment: Okay I take your opinion on board dude. I'm actually a computational geometry expert and in my work we use allot of Renaissance/Enlightenment inspired literature.

The reason I brought up Ergo was because I feel it is the most common English word (that is actually used) that can mean "Therefore" and in mystic scientific philosophy (and the quote) Therefore points to the origin, Therefore, I am.

It was too mystic for this board, won't do it again, sorry. Also I didn't even know Origo mean't the same thing in dialectics than either, so that turned out to be closer. Lol.